# Datepicker on concrete 5.8 only goes back 10 years

Tags: datepicker, concrete5

I have an attribute on my concrete5 site that asks for a birthday. on click it displays a datepicker, but when attempting to click a date, it only goes back ten years. I have already looked into this problem on other sites but all answers are for different versions of concrete with different folder locations so I don't know where to go or what to change.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend of mine found an answer on the [concrete community forums](https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/usage/date-picker-for-users-signing-up-only-goes-back-10-years/#868045), but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Concrete5 (8.1.0) goes 100 years back. 
If possible update...

If you can't update, please have a look at this github commit to the concrete5 core : 
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/pull/4864/commits/235f8a6598f5cf6b03c3c7b2d7c25ad32aee6ae1

Answer found at : https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/pull/4864